# How to properly wait until page loads before click() using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium

```
driver.find_element_by_id("ch4_loginGuestBtn").click()
```

This command intermittently fails with:

```
"Element is not clickable"
```

I'm guessing I need to do something like the following.

```
    guestlogin_button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.id, ".ch4_loginGuestBtn")))
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(guestlogin_button).click().perform()
```

This is however failing with:

```
AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'id'
```

What am I doing wrong, how do I fix the wait.until line?

Comment: I changed id to Id, still same issue.  The post you linked does not seem to be helping.

Comment: Other items in `By` use uppercase (`By.CSS_SELECTOR`, `By.XPATH`), so I would try `By.ID`.

Comment: changing to ID resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to change

```
guestlogin_button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.id, ".ch4_loginGuestBtn")))
```

to

```
guestlogin_button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, ".ch4_loginGuestBtn")))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int count=0;
while (count < 4) {
    try {
        Webdriverwait wait = new Webdriverwait(driver,10);
        WebElement p = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xapth("")));
        driver.findelement(by.xapth("")).click
     } 
     catch (Exception e) 
     {
         System.out.println("Trying to recover from a exception :-");
         count = count + 1;
         continue;
     } 

     count = count + 4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

bad code but works:

```
i=0
while i<1:
   try:
      driver.find_element_by_id("ch4_loginGuestBtn").click()
      i==1
   except:
```

time.sleep(1)
          i==0